# Using Vuetify on Select Components Only

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Will there be any future inconvenience/ compatibility errors if I just use Vuetify on only select components, and leave the others as is (made with vanilla html/js/css)?

I recently installed Vuetify on an existing project, and I'm not sure whether to recode the whole thing so I can integrate Vuetify into the whole project or just use it only on the components I will be making from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no inconvenience or any issues later on. You can use however much of Vuetify you wish for however much of your project you like.

The only downside I can think of is the visible difference between your own components and Vuetify components which will be apparent in the finished product. I would personally replace the old components with Vuetify in this case.